# Regex of multiple group in any order each of one multiplicity

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match strings where

1. there should be both `front/` and `back/` ignore case accompanied with at least one non-whitespace character
2. those two can be in any order
3. must begin with either group

The following are valid:

`front/asd dsa back/qwe ewq`

`back/dsafront/asd`

But not the following:

`asd front/asd back/qwe`

`front/asd back/asd front/asd`

I have tried the following in java:

`^(?=(((?i)front/)|((?i)back/)))(?=.*front/\s*\S)(?=.*back/\s*\S)`

But it does not fail when more than one `front/` or `back/` exists.

Comment: What's wrong with `^(front/.*back/.*|back/.*front/.*)$`?

Comment: Nice, i missed that one. Can you put it as an answer?

Comment: OK, I figured I must have misunderstood the requirements of the problem, but if this is what you're looking for, then great.

Comment: I was in the train of thought for multiplicites as another regex i have to do is one where theres one front and at least one back meaning there can be more than one back but only one front. So i figure I should detect one multiplicity in this problem. But ur solution works for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `^(front/.*back/.*|back/.*front/.*)$` matches either:

- `front/`, then anything, then `back/`, then anything; or
- `back/`, then anything, then `front/`, then anything.

The `^` and `$` mean the regex must match the whole string, not just a part of it. You can add capture groups using parentheses as required, so e.g. if you want the "anything"s it could look like this:

`^(front/(.*)back/(.*)|back/(.*)front/(.*))$`

Group 1 will always match the whole string; the part after `front/` will be in either group 2 or group 5, and the part after `back/` will be in either group 3 or group 4.